# AuthLogic seems to update the user record multiple times for one request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, authlogic

For one action request I see about 6 counts of what seems to be AuthLogic related record updates for the User model. I am wondering if this is normal, or if anyone else has encountered this and what can I do about it. I'm still trying to track down the cause of this, but I highly suspect it's AuthLogic related.

As you can see the updates to the record are quite slow and having all of these happen within one request is worrisome!

```
SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:43', `perishable_token` = 'rGvsUjfDYw4lrFk6bYJu', `updated_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:43' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697
  SQL (91.8ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:43', `perishable_token` = 'CHSKWhMmNHB5h8HeAWI', `updated_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:43' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697
  SQL (43.2ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:44', `perishable_token` = 'yDEGFCy4JrKrLVOKhwP', `updated_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:44' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697
  SQL (43.4ms)  COMMIT

User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:44', `perishable_token` = 'TSrzZCKL2C0R5BPJAkVA', `updated_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:44' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697
  SQL (36.6ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:44', `perishable_token` = 'hfRuoHYvIQZCdd8obtA', `updated_at` = '2012-06-22 22:02:44' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6697
  SQL (38.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Have you found the cause? I'm seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug around and found a solution:

> `UserSession.last_request_at_threshold = 10.minutes`

As I understand the place to set this - is in UserSession. ( This can be set in initalizer as well, like authlogic.rb)

The reason there are multiple updates is that it updates last_request_at **EVERY** time you do some kind of check against current_user. For instance when you use sign in status for some kind of work flow  - i.e. to display menu items or parts of the page only for the users that are logged in.

Once you set last_request_at to a larger threshold - you get rid of these updates. For me that gets rid of about 10 update statements - each was taking about 0.5 ms - not a big his, but considering that I have 100 users ( internal app) - using this app all the time, and I don't need to track their last requests ( they are either in the building or not), I can limit it or even stop tracking it altogether - over the course of the day that's a 10's of thousands of extra updates to the db I don't need to make - and makes reading logs easier.

**UPDATE**

Even if you set it to just 1 second - that will still help - because now it will only update once of every request ( assuming your app doesn't have requests that take longer than a second - if you do that maybe a sign of another problem) Even if you check against current_user multiple times in the same request. I doubt there are any humans that can do multiple different requests at the same second.

Hope this helps

P.S.: Here is the q that started me on the right path: [AuthLogic perishable_token resets on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901644/authlogic-perishable-token-resets-on-every-request)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know the last time a user requested a page, you can simply remove the database field and Authlogic won't do anything.

> Every time a session is found the last_request_at field for that record is
> updated with the current time, if that field exists.
> https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/0c9da9db0cafd28c8abe5528549dac6c639a0dbd/lib/authlogic/session/base.rb#L828-L829

For example to generate a rails migration:

```
rails generate migration RemoveLastRequestAtFromUsers last_request_at:datetime
```